# Can't connect to local server

Tags: networking, backup

Currently we have a system in place where multiple server backup to a server in house. There are a total of 11 different servers backing up to this one storage server. Without any change(any that we are aware of) one of the servers stopped being able to connect to the storage server. It's weird too because the one that can't connect is actually our DNS server. It can ping the storage server and nslookup returns the appropriate value. However when I tried to browse to the server in windows explore via network I get the following message:

"Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose." - Error Code: 0x800004005 Unspecified error.

If at all possible I would like the solution to not have to restart the server(obviously that's a big request) but we run 24/7 and can't have the DNS server down for the next few weeks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am completely guessing here however lets start with this, does it work if you try and connect to the share using IP?

A few things to consider in the mean time?  What O.S is it?

-> Is network discovery off?

-> Have any firewalls been accidentally turned on

-> We had a similar sort of problem when the server lost it's trust relationship with AD (required a reboot I am afraid).

Unfortunately this error can relate to a range of problems including network devices, anti-virus, firewalls, shares, user accounts etc etc.

Comment: OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

Connecting using the IP does not work.

Network discovery is on.

All firewalls are off.

I figured we would need a reset but I was hoping to avoid that. I understand that is not always an option though